# How to change the font type on a python graph text

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am displaying this text on a graph but I need it to be displayed in a different type of font. How do I do this? I also need the x^3 + 3x^2 + 4x to be displayed in the correct format as if it were to be written without the ^ .

```
plt.text(-5,250,'f(x) = x^3 + 3x^2 + 4x',fontsize=16,fontstyle='italic')
plt.text(3,150,'f(x)',fontsize=16,fontstyle='italic')
plt.text(3,-180,'-f(x)',fontsize=16,fontstyle='italic')
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the font family, pass the `family` keyword:

```
plt.text(-5,250,'f(x) = x^3 + 3x^2 + 4x',fontsize=16,fontstyle='italic', family='serif')
```

You can choose from `['serif' | 'sans-serif' | 'cursive' | 'fantasy' | 'monospace']`

See http://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html for more info

---

> I also need the x^3 + 3x^2 + 4x to be displayed in the correct format as if it were to be written without the ^ .

To do this do as @Ken suggested and use a raw string: `r'f(x) = x^3 + 3x^2 + 4x'`

Comment: To make the equation display as requested, make it raw text by adding a 'r' before it so that you have `r'f(x) = x^3 + 3x^2 + 4x'`.

Comment: Cheers I added that part with your name on it